# Variable name of a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to name a worksheet in excel as the value inside cell "C6" in the tab named "Control". I am new to VBA and what I tried was typing this on a module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Dim month As String
    month = Sheet2.Range("C5")
    Sheets("Month").Name = month
End Sub
```

Moreover, I do not know whether the name will be updated automatically. I do not want to have to run a macro to change the worksheet name...

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to get the value from "C6" from the sheet "Control" you'd just write `month = Sheets("Control").Range("C6").Value`. The syntax for your renaming is correct, but you'd only change the name of the sheet called "month" and that's it. Is that what you want? Also, for the automated updating I recommend using events.

Comment: Thanks @pawrick Yes, that is what I want. And I want this name to change when the user clicks on the "Refresh" button from the Control tab, which event should I use?

Comment: Which button exactly do you mean by refresh button? If you mean the calculate button then it's just the `Calculate` event from the according worksheet. Or you could just make your own button if you want the user to press a button anyways.

Comment: @pawrick maybe he has some external data to refresh with the month as a part of it. If it's the case, it's worksheet change event

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to be able to always refer to the same worksheet, regardless of the worksheet's name changing (as shown on the worksheet's tab) .

This is where the worksheets' **`CODENAME` Property** comes in handy.

Let's say you have an object variable declare for your worksheet like `Dim ws As Worksheet`.  You can refer to a worksheet three basic ways.

---

> ### ...by `Name` :
>
> > **Set object variable:**
> >
> > ```
> > Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
> > ```
>
> The worksheet name is the only worksheet identifier that can be changed to whatever you want, which (as you're probably aware) is done like:
>
> ```
> ws.Name = "NewSheetname"
> ```
>
> ...or alternatively, like:
>
> ```
> Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "NewSheetName"
> ```

---

> ### ...by `Index` Number :
>
> The index number identifies *the position of the worksheet's "tab"*, compared to the others (and cannot be changed without changing the order of the worksheets)
>
> > **Set object variable:**
> >
> > ```
> > Set ws = Sheets(1)
> > ```
>
> ...then you could (still) change the worksheets name like:
>
> ```
> ws.Name = "NewSheetname"
> ```
>
> ...or you could change the name by referring to the worksheet index number like:
>
> ```
> Sheets(1).Name = "NewSheetName"
> ```
>
> **NOTE:** If the worksheet is moved (or another worksheet is inserted before it), **the Index number will change!**  Therefore, it's usually not the preferred method of referring to a worksheet.

---

> ### ...by `CodeName` :
>
> The CodeName is how Excel refers to the worksheets internally.  It is the original name that Excel gave the worksheet, and it does not change since it is a read-only property.
>
> > **Set object variable:**
> >
> > ```
> > Set ws = Sheet1
> > ```
>
> ...then you could (still) change the worksheets name like:
>
> ```
> ws.Name = "NewSheetname"
> ```
>
> ...or you could change the name by referring to the worksheet codename like:
>
> ```
> Sheet1.Name = "NewSheetName"
> ```
>
> You can check a worksheets' **`CodeName`** property like:
>
> ```
> MsgBox Sheets("YourSheetName").CodeName
> ```
>
> ...or, if `ws` is already referencing the worksheet:
>
> ```
> MsgBox ws.CodeName
> ```

So, in your case, you could change the name of your worksheet as often as you like, with:

```
Sheet2.Name = "NewNameHere"
```

...just keep referring to it as `Sheet2`.

---

**One more example** to clarify the difference:

- Create a new workbook.  (It will automatically have worksheet named `Sheet1`.)
- Change the worksheet name to "Sheet1999", either manually (by double-clicking the name on it's tab) or programmatically (with `Sheet1.Name="Sheet1999"`)
- Now, if you want to find out how many rows on that sheet have been used, you use use either:

  ```
  MsgBox Sheets("Sheet1999").UsedRange.Rows.Count
  ```

  *...or:*

  ```
  MsgBox Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  ```

---

> ## *A note about `Sheets` versus `Worksheets`:*

When referring to a worksheet `Sheets` and `Worksheets` can *usually* be used interchangeably, so for example these two lines do the **same thing**:

```
Worksheets("mySheet").Calculate

Sheets("mySheet").Calculate
```

**The difference** is that:

- the `Worksheets` object searches **the `Worksheets` Collection** for a matching *Name*, *Index*, or *CodeName*.
- the `Sheets` object searches **the `Worksheets` Collection **and** the `Charts` Collection** for a matching *Name*, *Index*, or *CodeName*.

Therefore, the only time it would be a problem is if you have **a chart and a worksheet with the same name**.

So, **don't ever name a chart the same as a worksheet**, and then you won't have to worry about it, and can go on saving 4 keystrokes any time you refer to a *`Sheet`*...  :)

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**`Worksheet` Object**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-object-excel)
- MSDN : [**`Worksheet` Properties**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/dn301176.aspx)
- MSDN : [**`Worksheet` Methods**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/dn301177.aspx)
- MSDN : [**`Sheets` Object**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/sheets-object-excel)

Comment: Dammit, beat me to it.  I'd add you can change the worksheets codename in the sheets properties where you have a `(Name)` property for the codename and a `Name` property for the tab name.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook ...and I'm not sure but I *think* the `CodeName` always starts with `Sheet` - but i'm not sure if that includes all cases like imported/created/merged worksheets...?

Comment: When you create a new sheet the code name is always `Sheetx` where the _x_ is the sheet number.  You can change this in the _Properties_ window (F4 to open) to anything you like (within naming convention rules).  I'd expect an imported sheet to have the same codename it was in the source workbook - no doubt there's something in there to handle naming conflicts when importing.